# How to find index of element in collection without jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, indexing

I have a collection of elements in a div

lets say:

```
<div>
  <p id="one">one</p>
  <p id="two">two</p>
  <p id="three">three</p>
  <p id="four">four</p>
</div>
```

now I am looking for a simple way of finding the index of lets say the third element like this:

```
document.getElementById("three").index();
```

this should return an integer with the value of 2 since this element is the third

i know there is somehing like this in jquery but i would love plain js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in `indexOf` property of the Array object, as so:

```
 var child_element  = document.getElementById('three');
 var parent_element = child_element.parentNode;
 var i = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent_element.children, child_element);
```

Comment: You need to do `parent_element.children`

Comment: That wont work, we are selecting the child because it has a unique ID amd we are using the selector already anyway.  The code should work fine just as it is.

Comment: Hmm, did you try it? Because it returns `-1` without `.children`

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/KLWKT/1/

Comment: Good call Amir, thank you for the fix.